# SPSS - Rank and Partition

Tags: spss, rank

In SPSS Statistics Syntax File, I am looking to create a variable that calculates rank based on a desired partitioned column (e.g. equivalent to SQL "rank over (partition by column_a order by column b)" in Oracle SQL developer).

Please see the example:

Initial data without any filters:

[image]

Final output after applying get_rank:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If indeed you only need the key to filter for `key=1` then you can use this:

```
SORT CASES BY column_a column_b .
match files /file=* /by column_a /first=key1.
```

Now variable `key1` will have value 1 for every first occurence of a `column_a` category, and you can use it to `filter` or `select`.

For a full ranking variable you can use this (don't even need to sort first):

```
RANK VARIABLES=b (A) BY a /RANK  /TIES=MEAN.
```

Comment: This one really came in handy recently, thank you: RANK VARIABLES=b (A) BY a /RANK  /TIES=MEAN.

Answer (score 1):

To create a rank variable as described, first sort your data and then use the `LAG` function.

```
SORT CASES BY column_a column_b .
compute rank=1 .
IF ($CASENUM>1 AND column_a=LAG(column_a)) rank=LAG(rank) + 1 .
EXE .
```

`LAG` will look at the value of column_a for the prior case. In the syntax above it checks whether the value in column_a is different from that of the prior case.

If it has, then it will set the rank to 1. If it hasn't, then it will add 1 to the rank of the prior case. Just make sure your data is properly sorted first.

From there, if you want to look only at records that are rank=1, you can either use `FILTER BY` or `SELECT IF` to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem @ChrisV -- please consider selecting it as an answer if it helped you.